# Jquery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '324' in

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm trying to send a Get request by ajax and output json data that is returned by server in html.

But, I got this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '324' in 
[{"id":50,"name":"SEO"},{"id":22,"name":"LPO",}]
```

This is my code that sends a Get request to php file by ajax.
When I use $.each method, it get the error that I showed in the above.

```
parentCat.on('change', function(e){
    parentCatId = $(this).val();

    $.get(
        'index.php?r=admin/post/ajax',
        {"parentCatId":parentCatId},
        function(data){                     
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                console.log(key + ":" + value)
            })
        }
    )

})
```

This is my PHP code that returns query result in json format.

```
public function actionAjax(){

    $parentCatId=$_GET['parentCatId'];

        $catData = Category::getTargetCategoryData($parentCatId);
        
        echo CJSON::encode($catData);
        Yii::app()->end();
    
}
```

json data outputted by this php is like this.

```
[{"id":50,"name":"SEO"},{"id":22,"name":"LPO",}]
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Where does that error message come from?

Comment: can you add a `console.log(data)` before the `each` stmt and see what is printed in the console

Comment: Thank you! my problem got solved now :)

Comment: This may help someone - landed here but my problem was using `$.each('selector')...` instead of `$('selector').each(...`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have a JSON string, not an object. Tell jQuery that you expect a JSON response and it will parse it for you. Either use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), or pass the dataType argument to `$.get`:

```
$.get(
    'index.php?r=admin/post/ajax',
    {"parentCatId":parentCatId},
    function(data){                     
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            console.log(key + ":" + value)
        })
    },
    'json'
);
```

Comment: For anyone that comes here from Google looking for this problem the $.post, adding the same third parameter to $.post works too

Answer (score 22):

You can also use `$.parseJSON(data)` that will explicit convert a string thats come from a PHP script to a real JSON array.

Answer (score 6):

If you're fetching JSON, use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson) so it automatically converts the JSON to a JS Object.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed a similar error by adding the json dataType like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someUrl",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        varname1 : "varvalue1",
        varname2 : "varvalue2"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (varname, varvalue){
            ...
        });  
    }
});
```

And in my controller I had to use double quotes around any strings like so (note: they have to be escaped in java):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getJsonData(@RequestBody String parameters) {
    // parameters = varname1=varvalue1&varname2=varvalue2
    String exampleData = "{\"somename1\":\"somevalue1\",\"somename2\":\"somevalue2\"}";
    return exampleData;
}
```

So, you could try using double quotes around your numbers if they are being used as strings (and remove that last comma):

```
[{"id":"50","name":"SEO"},{"id":"22","name":"LPO"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getJSON

```
$.getJSON(
'index.php?r=admin/post/ajax',
{"parentCatId":parentCatId},
function(data){                     
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        console.log(key + ":" + value)
    })
});
```

Detail look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to tell the type controller that the response is a JSON object.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```