# JQuery AutoComplete with Remote Data (COLDFUSION)

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm a newbie with JQuery trying to pull remote data from a ColdFusion query to show in my textbox.

I am receiving an error in firebug when calling my CFC:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '453' in

I don't know what this may mean. I can see that is pulling data from my database because further down in my console output, I see my data:

```
[{"value":1,"label":"Test article"}] jquery-1.10.2.js:997
```

Can anyone help on this error?

**Full HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <!---Autocomplete Script --->
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <!---<script src="Scripts/auto_correct.js" type="text/javascript"></script> --->

    <script>
      $(function() {
             $( "#searchField" ).autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "kb/cfcs/search.cfc?method=lookupTitle&returnformat=json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                searchterm: request.term
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                response(data);
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    minLength: 3,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#searchField').val(ui.item.value);
                        $('#defaultArticleID').val(ui.item.label);
                    }
                });
            });
      </script>

</head>

<body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">
  ...      
  <!--- Main Container --->
  <div id="container">
       <cfform name="doesntmatter" method="post">
           <label for="searchField">Search KB Articles</label>
           <cfinput type="text" id="searchField" name="searchField" size="30em;" value=""/> 
           <cfinput type="hidden" name="defaultArticleID" id="defaultArticleID" value="0" />
       </cfform>
  </div>
  ...

</body>
</html>
```

**My CFC:**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="lookupTitle" access="remote" output="no" 
          hint="I return a list of titles" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfargument name="searchterm" required="false" default="" />

        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var returnArray =ArrayNew(1)>

        <!--- Do search --->
        <cfquery name="data" datasource="#datasource#">
            SELECT ID, title
            FROM kbArticles
            WHERE title LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#arguments.searchterm#%" />
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Build result array --->
        <cfloop query="data">
            <cfset titleStruct = structNew() />
            <cfset titleStruct['value'] = ID />
            <cfset titleStruct['label'] = title />

            <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray,titleStruct) />    
        </cfloop>

        <!--- And return it --->
        <cfreturn returnArray />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**UPDATE**

When making the suggested changes, i still recieve no data in my autocomplete form field. If I enable ** Enable Request Debugging Output** in my CFADMIN console, I see this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined .

When I click on the link next to the error in the console output, this is what it shows:

```
function writeToWindow( win ) {
    if( document.getElementById ) { // NS6
        // failing on <table ... 100%> for unescape() ?, and failing on writeCSS without unescape(), no the issue is with ns6 writing out the <link> tag for css
        // NS6 needs unescape() or else it writes 'showHide%28%27cf_debug_parameters%27,%27img_cf_debug_parameters%27%29;' for methods
        //win.document.write(unescape(document.getElementById("cf_debug").innerHTML));
        //NS6.2 wants it escaped
        win.document.write(document.getElementById("cf_debug").innerHTML);
    } else {
       win.document.write(document.all['cf_debug'].innerHTML);
    }
    win.document.close();
    win.focus();
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `<CFFORM>` and `<CFINPUT>` tags to regular HTML `<FORM>` and `<INPUT>` tags. You're not using any of the extra functionality that these ColdFusion UI tags can offer, and they might be mucking up your custom JavaScript.

Comment: Did you search the archives first? A very quick search turned up a few threads for that error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in  . Also, specifying `&returnformat=json` in *both* the URL and the cffunction definition may cause problems. Try removing it from the function definition. Test it out by invoking the method in your browser `http://yourserver.com/kb/cfcs/search.cfc?method=lookupTitle&returnformat=json&searchterm={somethinghere}`

Comment: OK, so changing my form to an HTML type and removing returntype="JSON" from my function definition had no effect. When I browser directly to my CFC, I see my data output as follows:

[{"value":1,"label":"Test article"}]

Answer (score 2):

(Expanded from comments...)

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502129/104223), the error means the code was expecting a parsed JSON *object*, but was passed a simple *string* instead. jQuery is not parsing your cfc response string into a JSON object. Instead it is just passing the plain string into the response() function, which causes an error because that function expects an array. The reason the response is not parsed automatically is that `datatype` has the wrong case. It should be:

```
     dataType: "json"  // Note, upper case "T"
```

As an aside, do not forget to `var/local` scope ALL of your function local variables, including query names.

**Update:**

I think a simpler approach here would be to change the cffunction argument name to `term` then use a URL as the source. Also, since you are not using any of the extra features of cfform, may as well switch to plain html elements instead.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
         $( "#searchField" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/kb/cfcs/search.cfc?method=lookupTitle&returnformat=json",
                minLength: 3,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#searchField').val(ui.item.value);
                    $('#defaultArticleID').val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });
        });
</script>  
...
<form>
    <label for="searchField">Search field: </label>
    <input id="searchField">
    <input id="defaultArticleID">
</form>
```

Comment: Made the changes, now it doesn't throw any errors in firebug, but no data is displayed. Either in the console or the text box.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Can you update your question with your stand alone HTML test page?

Comment: No I meant with the complete html test page (JS includes, form fields, etc..). Basically a stand alone example, any one could plug in and run with their own .cfc.  BTW, I rolled back the update because without the original error message .. my response makes no sense ;-) Better to *append* changes, than overwrite the original question.

Comment: Yep, anywhere is fine. Most people preface the new text with a small header like "Edit" or "Update", but it is not required. It is more about preserving the context of the original question, so the next guy having the same problem can read through the issue(s) you experienced and the solutions all in one thread.

Comment: (Edit) See my updated response. FYI: I trimmed the updated example to include only the relevant HTML code. What you had originally was perfect. I just wanted to see a little extra (JS includes and form fields) to verify the id's and such were correct :)

Comment: OK cool. I'm starting to think my CF9 is the culprit. Your latest updates make the JS much simpler and the fact that no data is coming back, makes me think that something is wrong with CFServer not allowing it..?? Am I off base? 

Is there any way to output to the console the query data that is recieved in JQUERY into the firebug console? Just to be able to see if the data is actually received from the the CFC request?

Comment: (Edit) If it is received, you should see it in the console. Make sure you disable CF debugging because the extra HTML will break the JSON response string. Try this standalone example. It uses the sample "cfartgallery" database:  http://pastebin.com/aZGJiewR

Comment: The cfdump is showing a bunch of data, 55 records total. So we know the data is there and accessable.

When I put a cursor in the textbox, I see this line added to the console: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. 

But typing either the ARTID or ARTNAME values in the textbox yields nothing. No data or no errors in the console.

Comment: Works fine for me w/CF9, which suggests a difference in your environment. So as not to overlook the obvious, 1) Did you run the example *exactly* "as is" 2) Re-verify the remote method runs by running the cfc in your browser first? 3) Fix the jquery URL to match the location of the .cfc on your machine? 4) Are there any Application.cfc files that might be interfering? If yes, move the test files to another directory.

Comment: 1)The only thing I changed was the path to the CFC. put the CFC in the same dir as my CFM page and not in my normal CFCS directory with my other cfc's. This also answers question 3. Path was changed to: Foo.cfc?method=lookupTitle&returnformat=json

2)Ran CFC in browser and it appears to work: http://pastebin.com/95TbmNxy

3)Answered in response 1)

4)Moving my CFC into the same directory as my CFM page should answer this point. There are no other CFC's in this dir. I'm also running CF8. Anything to check on with respect to the server? Other CFC's run in my app without any apparent issues.

Comment: Everything seems fine except maybe #4) Application.cfc files apply to subdirectories too. So any Application.cfc is anywhere in the *parent* folders (grandparent,etcetera)?

Comment: OK, so you were right. My application.cfc file was causing some sort of problem. I created a blank application.cfc file in my original CFCS directory and moved foo.cfc in there, updated my code and now the JQuery autocorrect works. I should have known because when I was reading your text, I remembered having a similar issue years ago and a light-bulb went off. I never figured out what the conflict was, just as easy to leave the blank CFC file in there as it doesn't adversely effect my application in any way. Thank you much for you extended help. Gonna try my original code from this post now.

Comment: The orginal code in my updated question is now working! Definately application.cfc breaking it somehow. I noticed that when I type a letter in the text box, it lists all the records in that table, not just the ones that records that have that letter in the title field. Does that mean my query in my CFC is incorrect?

Comment: ------ UPDATE: if I change my quesry to WHERE title LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#url.term#%" /> it has the desired effect.

Comment: You should not have to use `url.term`. Sounds like you forgot to change the the cfargument name from `searchterm` to `term` in the real .cfc , so it is using the default instead `(empty string)`. That is why it was returning all records. (Glad everything is working now)

Comment: Once again, that did it. Thanks for paying forward!