# jQueryUI autocomplete - unable to display returned selection (Coldfusion)

Tags: jquery-ui, coldfusion

This is driving me crazy. I'm using jQueryUI autocomplete to pull back customer name and customer id pairs. The user should be able to start typing a customer name and get a list of suggestions, select from the list and upon selection the customer id should be assigned to a hidden field. The autocomplete is working fine up to the point of assigning the values selected. The user can start typing and get a list of suggestions and select one. At this point the value in the text field will change to the customer id instead of the customer name, which is the problem in a nutshell.

jQuery code:

```
$( "#enaCustomer" ).autocomplete({
    source: "customerLookup.cfc?method=lookupCustomer&returnformat=json",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui);
        console.log(ui.item.label);
        $('#enaCustomer').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#enaCusID').val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

CFC:

```
<cffunction name="lookupCustomer" access="remote" output="no" returnformat="JSON">

    <cfargument name="term" required="true" default="" />

    <!--- Define variables --->
    <cfset var returnArray = ArrayNew(1)>

    <!--- Do search --->
    <cfquery name="rsCustomers" datasource="myDB">
        SELECT      cusID, cusCustomer
        FROM        tblCustomers
        WHERE       cusCustomer LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#term#%" />
        ORDER BY    cusCustomer
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Build result array --->
    <cfloop query="rsCustomers">
        <cfset customerStruct = structNew() />
        <cfset customerStruct['value'] = cusID />
        <cfset customerStruct['label'] = cusCustomer />

        <cfset arrayAppend(returnArray, customerStruct) />    
    </cfloop>

    <!--- And return it --->
    <cfreturn returnArray />

</cffunction>
```

`console.log(ui)` shows this for example customer:

item: Object { label: "Customer 4", value: 4 }

`console.log(ui.item.label)`:

```
"Customer 4"
```

but this simply appears not to work:

```
$('#enaCustomer').val(ui.item.label);
```

There's got to be something simple I'm missing here, but I don't know what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: The first problem I see without looking into it further is that you have `returnformat=json` in both the function definition and in the ajax call.  You should only have it one or the other.

Comment: You say `console.log` shows `label: "Customer 4" `. Where does the keyword `item` come from, that you use `ui.item.label` later?

Comment: @user12031119 - removed returnformat=json from the ajax call but has no affect on the issue.

Comment: @Bernhard - I think I muddled things there. It should look like this - item: Object { label: "Customer 3", value: 3 }. Let me edit that.

Comment: QQ; Which version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I conflated your scenario to this which I thought was the source of your problem.  https://www.raymondcamden.com/2008/06/03/Be-careful-with-returnFormat-and-JSON

Comment: By the way, if you're interested in refactoring your code a bit, I've coded my remote autocomplete just like this and it works perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801780/jquery-autocomplete-with-remote-data-coldfusion

Comment: @user12031119 - no problem, I appreciate the response. Re refactoring code, the post you linked to is actually what I modeled my code on. I'm not sure where it is materially different. That's what's so baffling.

Comment: @Adrian - ColdFusion 2016

Comment: In your `select` you may want to `return false;` at the end. I don't see anything that is jumping out as incorrect. You may also want to add `console.log(ui.item)` to ensure that the item object is passing correctly. Can you gather the results from the Network console and include them for testing?

Comment: The biggest difference in the link supplied was from the `source:` attribute.  Whereas you're calling the cfc as a direct link, the other way (which does work for me) calls it via ajax.  Perhaps, the `dataType: "json"` attribute in the ajax call is enough to get you the desired result.

Comment: As @Twisty suggested, `return: false;` in the `select` option might serve you well.  I looked at my own code that successfully works and sure enough, I coded `return: false;`.

Comment: @user12031119 "*When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one. The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.*"

Comment: @Twisty - adding "return false;" at the send of the select seems to have done it. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses.

Comment: mpaul - I'm glad you got this working.  If either you or @Twisty adds `return: false;` as an answer, I'll be sure to be one of the upvoters as I believe this is a valuable piece of information.  Nice job of explaining your problem and nice job to Twisty on coming up with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Demo: [jQuery UI | AutoComplete | Custom Data](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Would advise the following:

```
$("#enaCustomer").autocomplete({
  source: "customerLookup.cfc?method=lookupCustomer&returnformat=json",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#enaCustomer').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#enaCusID').val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
  }
});
```

This causes the function to end without performing any further actions.