# How to add string returned using GET to backbone model?

Tags: c#, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api2

I have this ApiController that returns only one column from the table.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetEmailConfig()
{
    return dbContext.EmailConfig.Select(m => m.smtpHost).AsEnumerable();
}
```

I only need to return the smtpHost but not the other fields in the database table. This returns as 
[smtp.host]
0: "smtp.host"

How can I add this to my backbone model properly? Currently, it's showing up in attributes like this:

```
attributes: Object
0: "["
1: """
2: "s"
3: "m"
4: "t"
5: "p"
6: "."
7: "a"
8: "b"
9: "c"
10: "."
11: "d"
12: "e"
13: "f"
14: """
15: "]"
```

I think I have to serialize the string but not sure how to do it or if that's what the problem is. Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
my model

```
App.Models.EmailConfigModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response, option)
    {
        var smtpHost = "";
        console.log('parsing smtp host');
        $.each(response, function (index, val) {

            smtpHost = smtpHost + val;
        });
        return { "smtpHost": smtpHost };
    }
});
```

I also tried `return{"attributeName": smtpHost };` and just "attributename". None worked.

This is how I fetch from my Index page

```
App.emailconfig.fetch().then(function () {
    new App.Views.EmailConfig({ collection: App.emailconfig });
});
```

And this is my collection:

```
App.Collections.EmailConfig = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.EmailConfigModel,
    url: 'api/EmailConfig',

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in fetch, and save. The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the attributes hash to be set on the model

so in your model write a parse function like

```
parse : function(response,option){
  var mystr = "";
    $.each($.parseJSON(response), function(index, val) {
             mystr = mystr + val;
        });
   return {"attributenmae" : mystr};
}
```

Comment: I used your function but I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '15' in ["smtp.xxx.xxx"]. I changed the smtp host.

Comment: i assume you want the property to be saved as 
{"attributenmae" : "smtp.host"} in backbone model , am i right?

Comment: Sure, but what do you need? Model, Collection or C#? I did exactly the same as you did in the model

Comment: place where you did this operation.

Comment: I just added my Model, Collection and how it's fetched from the Index page.

Comment: use this as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in

Answer (score 0):

write a parse method that returns a object `{attributeName:stringReturnedFromService}`