# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '728' in

Tags: javascript, php

I am json encoding it from the php back to this js file, and I am getting the cannot use 'in' operator to search. I window.alert(data) and it looks correct.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '728' in {"0":{"Name":"Duncan Davis","0":"Duncan Davis","Type":"Student","1":"Student"},"1":{"Name":"Andrew Mackey","0":"Andrew Mackey","Type":"Professor","1":"Professor"},"2":{"Name":"Joe Smith","0":"Joe Smith","Type":"Student","1":"Student"},"3":{"Name":"John Hightower","0":"John Hightower","Type":"Professor","1":"Professor"},"4":{"Name":"Cat collectors","0":"Cat collectors","Type":"Group","1":"Group"},"5":{"Name":"Database Knowledge","0":"Database Knowledge","Type":"Group","1":"Group"},"6":{"Name":"Dictionary","0":"Dictionary","Type":"Book","1":"Book"},"7":{"Name":"Dictionary Of Cats","0":"Dictionary Of Cats","Type":"Book","1":"Book"},"8":{"Name":"Dictionary Of POTATOES","0":"Dictionary Of POTATOES","Type":"Book","1":"Book"}}

```
$(function () {
$("#login_form").on('submit', function () {

    var Input = document.test.Input.value;
window.alert(Input);

    // use ajax to run the check
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/DBConnect.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: Input,
        success: DataReturn,
        error: function (xhr, status, err) { }
    });

    return false;
});

function DataReturn(Data) {

    window.alert(Data);

var tableheader = "<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead>";

    $('#table').empty();

    $('#table').append(tableheader);

    $.each(Data, function (index, item) {
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>'
        + item['Name']
        + '</td><td>'
        + item['Type']
        + '</td></tr>');
    });

}
```

});

Comment: You code does not use the word `in`, what are you actually asking about? Additionally: don't use the `window` prefix (it's already global scope), nor `alert`: use `console.log`.

Comment: what line in the code you provided is the error occurring?  where are you using the word `in`?

Comment: try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in

Comment: jquery.js:862 there are not 862 lines to the js file. I am not using the word in anywhere

Comment: it's a datatype issue.  I have to go do something.  I'll be back in about 10 min if you haven't figured it out yet.  It has to do with your use of `data` in that `$.each`.

Comment: hmm, im working on it still not getting it.

Comment: @user1552172 What does your server page serve?  A content type of json, or string?

Comment: echo json_encode($testsql,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); is what i am using to json results back to js

Comment: @user1552172 That doesn't answer my question; what is the content type?

Comment: Json is what i was thinking

Comment: _" I window.alert(data) and it looks correct."_ - If an alert displays your JSON then that means your `Data` variable is still a _string_ so you can't treat it as an object. It needs to be parsed, which jQuery will do for you if you add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax()` options, or if you set the response headers in your PHP to have the right type.

Comment: `using (function()[ RETURN 1; ])();`

Comment: Ah ok so now that i have it as a json object in the ajax, how do i go through the object ?

Comment: _Then_ you can use `$.each()`.

Comment: Well i am not getting an error but i am not getting each element added to the table like it should. do i need to change anything in my $.each() statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../php/DBConnect.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: Input,
    success: DataReturn,
    error: function (xhr, status, err) { }
});
```

add `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../php/DBConnect.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: Input,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: DataReturn,
    error: function (xhr, status, err) { }
});
```

Comment: This turns my results into a [object object]

Comment: @user1552172 That's an object converted to a string; this is why you don't use `alert()`, but rather `console.log()`.

Comment: I was using it just for debug, now i have it as console.log() but i am trying to get my $.each to add to the table but it seems like the Item part of the $.each is not happening.