# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '25' in

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Struggling to figure this error. I understand its to do with the String not being a JSON object, however i cant fix it!

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '25' in ["fgdf","dfergerg","Save"]
```

This is my funciton:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".userIcon").click(function() {
        var groupUsername = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "groupUserList.php",
           data:{"groupUsername" : groupUsername},
        }).done(function(data) {
            jQuery.each(data, function(name, value) {
                if (value !== 'Save') 
                {
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        console.log(value);
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Cheers

Comment: First check at PHP, what is it showing?

Comment: the second $(document)ready is rather useless as the dom has already loaded by the time you call on the `done` handler for the ajax. are you certain data is an object and not a string? Try a `console.log("type: ", typeof(data))` or `console.log(data)` sound similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in), a way to fix would be to explicitly set your response headers from php to `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it. Was just missing the dataType

```
 dataType: "json",
```