# TypeScript error cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' for typescript and pouchdb

Tags: javascript, typescript, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using pouchDb with Angular2 in a typescript environment with webstorm and systemjs. In the editor, it appears I have sufficent configuration to where I can get intellisense and pouchDB does run.

I have this test code.

```
  var mydb = new PouchDB('TestDb');
  var myObj = {"_id" : "1", "description":"hello world"} ;
  var objAsString = JSON.stringify(myObj) ;
  mydb.put(objAsString).then(function (response) {
      // handle response
      console.log("save to db:" + response) ;
  }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in {"_id":null,"description":"hello world"}
    at PouchDB.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:210:21)
    at PouchDB.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:11043:18)
    at PouchDB.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5996:21)
    at PouchDB.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:11043:18)
    at http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:8252:21
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$initializePromise (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1558:9)
    at new lib$es6$promise$promise$$Promise (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1849:9)
    at PouchDB.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:8239:19)
    at PouchDB.put (http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:11043:18)
    at http://localhost:63342/clipsalive/node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5991:32
```

I'm thinking it has to do with module loading, I've tried it with an without a value for _id with same result.

Is this a module loading problem and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '324' in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[put](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document)** method in PouchDb expects a JSON object not a string.

You should just send the object without stringifying it.

```
var myObj = {"_id" : "1", "description":"hello world"} ;
mydb.put(myObj)
```