# Unclear error when working with JSON data in jQuery: "cannot use 'in' operator to search for length"

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

I use an ajax function which gives me clean JSON data without problem:

```
    $.get(
        ajax_url,
        data,
        function(data) { // AJAX callback
            $("#tt").html(data);              //insert server response
            fill_json(data);
        }// End AJAX callback
```

However, I think that maybe there's a bug in my `fill_json(data);` function:

```
var fill_json = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + key.ID + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + key.post_title + "</td>" + "<td>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#testajax tbody");
        });
};
```

BTW, is this the easiest way to use JSON data you retrieve through AJAX?

My **JSON** data looks like this:

```
{"ID":"4066","post_title":"TATTOO SLEEVES","category":"Apparel & Accessories","slug":"apparel-and-accessories","supplier_company":"\u682a\u5f0f\u4f1a\u793e\u30bb\u30f3\u30bf\u30fc\u5546\u4e8b","allslug":"apparel-and-accessories, accessories, textiles, toys, gifts-toys-and-animation, english","allcatname":"Apparel & Accessories, Accessories, Textiles, Toys, Gifts, Toys & Animation, \u82f1\u8a9e"}]
```

Comment: please post your JSON Format as well

Comment: please post your serve side code

Comment: parse data variable into json format before loop through via $.parseJSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '324' in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in)

Comment: Satish Sam! Some data showed up in the table but it says "undefined" in the table. While The raw JSON looks fine... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**parse data variable into json format before loop through via $.parseJSON**

```
var fill_json = function(data){
    var jsonData=$.parseJSON(data); //change here
        $.each(jsonData, function(i) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + jsonData[i].ID + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + jsonData[i].post_title + "</td>" + "<td>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#testajax tbody");
        });
};
```

Comment: This works but both key.ID and key.post_title show up as "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.get(
        ajax_url,
        data,
        function(data) { // AJAX callback
            $("#tt").html(data);              //insert server response
```

var jsonData=$.parseJSON(data); // My Changes
                fill_json(jsonData);
            }// End AJAX callback

**fill_json**

```
var fill_json = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + value.ID + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + value.post_title + "</td>" + "<td>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#testajax tbody");
        });
};
```