# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '50602' in error(...)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've got a select box which changes the order of the results i'm returning from the database depending on the select box value chosen which is linked to a switch PHP statement, problem i'm having is that my JavaScript doesn't refresh my results to match the switch statement selected despite showing know errors on the JSON in the developer preview when the option change is selected, but the below error is thrown in the console and i presume this is whats stopping the results from updating in relation to the select option selected, any ideas on how to fix this JSON error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '50602' in error(...)

PHP:

```
   $batsmenQuery = Batsmen::where('approved', '=', 1);

   switch ($request->SortbyList){
        case 0:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
            break;
        case 1:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 2:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 3:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'DESC');
            break;
            default:
                $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');


    }

    $batsmen= $batsmenQuery->paginate(40);
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="sort">
            <select name="SortbyList" id="SortBy">
                <option value="0">A to Z</option>
                <option value="1">Z to A</option>
                <option value="2">Highest Score</option>
                <option value="3">Lowest Score</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $('#SortBy').on('change', function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url: "{{route('search.index')}}", // This is the url you make the request
         data: {SortbyList : this.value}, // Here you can send to the server the info you want in this case is only the value for the selected item
         success: function(result){

             if(result){
                 $("#SortBy").empty();  //This erase all the preview values
                 var new_options = '';
                 //This loop create the new values
                 $.each(result, function(k,v){
                     new_options += '<option value="'+ v.value +'">'+  v.name +'</option>'
                 });
                 //Now we have all the values we can put on the select
                 $("#SortBy").append(new_options);
             }

         }
 });
```

Comment: So you should debug the ajax response first.

Comment: i am, problem is with the ajax mainly that it is not updating the results on the live page but is showing successful requests in preview.

Comment: This could be it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in

Comment: Any chance of you applying that to my code through an answer as i don't understand that

Comment: Add `datatype: "jsonp",` below `url: "{{route('search.index')}}",`. SOme posts also says it can be `datatype: "json",`.

Comment: Ive added that and it now stops the error but the results showing on the live page don't change, in response to the selected option although it shows a selection change in network on dev tools

Comment: jquery might have a node refresh or node reload feature to make changes appears. Not an expert on jquery.